# How to create JSON Array in Bash

Tags: bash, jq, amazon-emr, ash

I want to create JSON array for emr steps. I have created the array for single json string. Here is my bash code -

```
export source="s3a://sourcebucket"
export destination="s3a://destinationbucket"

EMR_DISTCP_STEPS=$( jq -n \
                  --arg source "$source" \
                  --arg destination "$destination" \
                  '{
                    "Name":"S3DistCp step",
                    "HadoopJarStep": {
                    "Args":["s3-dist-cp","--s3Endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com", "'"--src=${sourcepath}"'" ,"'"--dest=${destinationpath}"'"],
                    "Jar":"command-runner.jar"
                    },
                     "ActionOnFailure":"CONTINUE"
                   }' )
```

output

```
echo $EMR_DISTCP_STEPS

[{ "Name": "S3DistCp step", "HadoopJarStep": { "Args": [ "s3-dist-cp", "--s3Endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com", "--src=s3a://sourcebucket", "--dest=s3a://destinationbucket" ], "Jar": "command-runner.jar" }, "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE" }]
```

Now I want to create JSON array with multiple source and destination 
output

```
[{ "Name": "S3DistCp step", "HadoopJarStep": { "Args": [ "s3-dist-cp", "--s3Endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com", "--src=s3a://sourcebucket1", "--dest=s3a://destinationbucket1" ], "Jar": "command-runner.jar" }, "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE" },
{ "Name": "S3DistCp step", "HadoopJarStep": { "Args": [ "s3-dist-cp", "--s3Endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com", "--src=s3a://sourcebucket2", "--dest=s3a://destinationbucket2" ], "Jar": "command-runner.jar" }, "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE" },
{ "Name": "S3DistCp step", "HadoopJarStep": { "Args": [ "s3-dist-cp", "--s3Endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com", "--src=s3a://sourcebucket3", "--dest=s3a://destinationbucket3" ], "Jar": "command-runner.jar" }, "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE" }]
```

How to generate JSON Array with multiple sources and destinations (JSON string) in Bash?

Comment: Are the three items supposed to be different from each other in any way? If so, where is the data used to distinguish them supposed to come from?

Comment: BTW, note that you don't want to conflate *syntactic* quotes with *literal* quotes. That is, in a shell command that contains an argument `'foo'`, the quote `'` is *an instruction to your shell*, not part of the argument `foo`, and you want to leave it out of any JSON or other higher-level representation of the data.

Comment: Consider converting your bash script into python - you will avoid so many pitfalls down the road.

Comment: @mvp, ...I fully agree that languages that are able to represent the structures you're trying to manipulate in-memory (and with parsing/generation facilities compliant with the format spec in question) are the right tool for manipulating structured data. That said, `jq` *is* such a language, just as much as Python is, and also happens to be already tagged in the question. :)

Comment: @lucy, ...by the way, a note about variable names -- POSIX specifies that all-caps names are reserved for variables that modify behavior of POSIX-defined utilities (and/or the shell itself), whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to modify compliant tools' behavior. As non-exported shell variables modify any preexisting environment variable under the same name, this guidance applies to both types; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to provide a `jq` function that generates your repeated structure, given the specific inputs you want to modify. Consider the following:

```sh
# generate this however you want to -- hardcoded, built by a loop, whatever.
source_dest_pairs=(
  sourcebucket1:destinationbucket1
  sourcebucket2:destinationbucket2
  sourcebucket3:destinationbucket3
)

# -R accepts plain text, not JSON, as input; -n doesn't read any input automatically
# ...but instead lets "inputs" or "input" be used later in your jq code.
jq -Rn '
  def instructionsForPair($source; $dest): {
    "Name":"S3DistCp step",
    "HadoopJarStep": {
      "Args":[
        "s3-dist-cp",
        "--s3Endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com",
        "--src=\($source)",
        "--dest=\($dest)"
      ],
      "Jar":"command-runner.jar"
    }
  };

  [ inputs 
  | capture("^(?<source>[^:]+):(?<dest>.*)$"; "")
  | select(.)
  | instructionsForPair(.source; .dest) ]
' < <(printf '%s\n' "${source_dest_pairs[@]}")
```

...correctly emits as output:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "S3DistCp step",
    "HadoopJarStep": {
      "Args": [
        "s3-dist-cp",
        "--s3Endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com",
        "--src=sourcebucket1",
        "--dest=destinationbucket1"
      ],
      "Jar": "command-runner.jar"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "S3DistCp step",
    "HadoopJarStep": {
      "Args": [
        "s3-dist-cp",
        "--s3Endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com",
        "--src=sourcebucket2",
        "--dest=destinationbucket2"
      ],
      "Jar": "command-runner.jar"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "S3DistCp step",
    "HadoopJarStep": {
      "Args": [
        "s3-dist-cp",
        "--s3Endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com",
        "--src=sourcebucket3",
        "--dest=destinationbucket3"
      ],
      "Jar": "command-runner.jar"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I got this error `syntax error near unexpected token <'` when running the above script

Comment: @DucTran, make sure you run it with `bash` not `sh`

Comment: I tried changing the order of the command then it worked. Something like: `printf ... |
 jq -Rn ...`

Comment: @DucTran, even though it isn't part of POSIX sh (and thus can only be used with bash and other shells supporting [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst)), the `<(...)` syntax is better for the reasons described in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: Thank you, I ran the original script with bash successfully.